# Why does inserting <div><%= render 'my_partial' %></div> w/ Coffeescript throw an error when the partial contains rails helper methods (e.g. link_to)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've noticed that if I insert a `<div>` with Coffeescript like this:

```
$('#container-1').slideUp 'slow', ->
    $('#container-2').html("<div class='row'><div class='small-12 columns'><%= render 'my_partial' %></div></div>")
    $('#container-2').slideDown()
```

And the partial contains a rails helper method such as `link_to` or `collection_select`, Coffeescript throws a syntax error. If I remove the `link_to` and replace it with a normal `<a href=...` tag that does the same thing I do not get an error.

Any idea what's causing this? How can I get around it so that I include helper methods in the partial?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** Coffeescript code. Most likely the partial contains a `"` and thus closing the string prematurely. A way to solve this would be to not render the partial inside a JavaScript string.

Comment: what error does it throw??

Comment: You need to at *least* JS- escape the rendering.

Comment: @FelixKling, how do I see the generated coffeescript? Thanks

Comment: Look at the source of the webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix suggests above, you're probably generating some invalid CoffeeScript due to unescaped quotation marks being inserted into your CoffeeScript string.

Try using the [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) helper method, or its handy alias `j`:

```
$('#container-1').slideUp 'slow', ->
  $('#container-2').html("<div class='row'><div class='small-12 columns'><%= j render 'my_partial' %></div></div>")
  $('#container-2').slideDown()
```